# Does there exist a function $f$ analytic on $0<|z|<1$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=\frac{1}{2n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f$ analytic on $0<|z|<1$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

This was an exercise right after discussing the Identity Theorem, so I obviously need to use it:

> Let $f,g$ be analytic on $D$. If $f\equiv g$ on some set $S\subseteq D$ which has an accumulation point in $D$, then $f\equiv g$ in $D$.

I tried disproving it by assuming that there *is* a function $f$ that satisfies the conditions. But with $S=\{\frac{1}{2n+1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<|z|<1\}$, there is no accumulation point in $D$ since $0\notin D$ so I can't use the Identity Theorem.

If I try proving it instead, how? This became a homework so please just give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Write $2n + 1 = 2n\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{2n}\bigr)$.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Sorry, switched $2n$ and $2n+1$. Write $2n = (2n+1)\bigl(1 - \frac{1}{2n+1}\bigr)$.

Comment: @Dante If you have found a solution to your posed problem, answer your own question instead of deleting it : this benefits other users too.

Comment: alright :) sorry bout that!